# Can't get to a value inside a player in lua

Tags: lua, roblox

Code I Tried

```
game.Workspace.burgerclick.OnServerEvent:Connect(function()
    local playername = game.Workspace.ClickPlayer.Value
    local player = game.Players:FindFirstChild(playername)
    local playaname = player.Name
    local fpval = game.Players[playaname].FP.Value
    fpval = fpval + 1
end)
```

I am making a game and I wanted to have a button that updates the value of something called FP, in the workspace I have a stringvalue called ClickPLayer which updates to the player clicking the button. that works. I made a variable that is the value the stringvalue, but when I put the variable inside the line when I update the FP Value it says the variable is not a valid member of players. I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Is FP an object inside the player in Players or the players character in the workspace?

Comment: FP is a Number Value inside all players

Comment: I'm trying to update the player that clicked it's FP Value

Comment: How was FP created? Your error message makes it sound like it doesn't exist when this code runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the correct code should be something like:

```
game.Players[playaname].FP.Value = game.Players[playaname].FP.Value + 1
```

Because, when you do:

```
 local fpval = game.Players[playaname].FP.Value
 fpval = fpval + 1
```

You are copying the value of `game.Players[playaname].FP.Value`to `fpval` and incrementing the copy (`fpval = fpval + 1`), not the value held by `game.Players[playaname].FP`.

Answer (score 0):

The most correct and efficient code would be

```lua
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local fpval
local plr
workspace.burgerclick.Activated:Connect(function()
    plr = workspace.ClickPlayer.Value
    fpval = Players[plr].FP
    fpval.Value = fpval.Value + 1
end)
```

In the documentation of [TextButtons](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/TextButton#Activated) and [ImageButtons](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/ImageButton#Activated), there is an `Activated` event that can be used for this, instead of firing a server from a `LocalScript` which is what your script aims to do now. However, if the button is in the PlayerGui and you have an activation `LocalScript` for it, you probably want to use this code instead:

```lua
local fpval
workspace.burgerclick.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(plr)
    fpval = plr.FP
    fpval.Value = fpval.Value + 1
end)
```